# How to call function on XMLHttpRequest status = true in Vue 2? I get "this.xxxx not a function" error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code, which works fine except for the "makeToast" function that I'm trying to call when status response is true. I get a "this.makeToast is not a function" error on the console.

This function is working fine if I call it after the XMLHttpRequest code. The data is also not being assigned to the msgForm property. I could not figure out why. The "alert(..." message work fine.

```
<script>

import ToastMixins from '/src/mixins/ToastMixins'

let config = {
    headers: {
    }
}

export default {
    name: 'ModalDestaque',
    mixins: [
        ToastMixins
    ],
 methods: {
  myFunction() {
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log('onreadystatechange');
        
        console.log('responseText 1', xhr.responseText);

        this.loading = false;

        if (xhr.status == 200) {

            console.log('responseText 2', xhr.responseText);
            let responseObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log('responseObj', responseObj);

            if (responseObj.status == true) {

                //alert('Ok');

                // this is not working:
                this.msgForm = "Message success!";
                this.makeToast('b-toaster-bottom-right', true, 'success');

            } else {

                alert('Not ok...');

            }

        }

    }
   };
  }
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is this function? Is it in a component ?

Comment: The function is in a vue Mixin imported to this component. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution while reading the docs at W3 Schools.

[W3 Schools AJAX XMLHttp - Multiple Callback Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp)

Although, I haven't found a working example anywhere.

In my code, at the button click event that triggers the XMLHttpRequest, I've added the function name "callToast" as a variable, so:

```
@click="onClickSubmit(myValue, myId, myTitle, callToast)"
```

Then in the script:

```
<script>
 onClickSubmit(amount, id, title, cFunction) {
 
  // stuff

  if (xhr.status == 200) {

   let responseObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

   if (responseObj.status == true) {
   
    // here I call the callToast function:
    cFunction(this);
    
    alert('Ok');
   
   } else {
    alert('Not ok...');
   }
  }
 },
 callToast() {
  this.msgForm = "Message success!";
  this.makeToast('b-toaster-bottom-right', true, 'success');
 }
</script>
```